# cocos2d 1.0.1 Warning: no preserveBackBuffer found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, buffer

I am running cocos2d 1.0.1. I am getting Warning Errors regarding this code saying that the initWithFrame method is not found. I believe it is responsible for crashing my application, while logging "Unknown Error"

```
glView = [[EAGLView alloc] initWithFrame:[window bounds]
                                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                               depthFormat:GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                                        preserveBackbuffer:NO];
```

This is the Build WARNING I got:

> WARNING: No '-initWithFrame: pixelFormat:
>   depthFormat:preserveBackbuffer:' method found

Reading forum posts from a year ago, Riq recommended the above method posted, but that did not work.

I do have my EAGLView.h/m files, they are under the iOS subFolder of the Platforms subFolder.

I tried adding an @class EAGLView; declaration in the App.h file, but I still couldn't even get Xcode to jump to the definition of the EAGLView class. Moving the two EAGLView .h and .m files up to the main Cocos2d folder did nothing either.

My question is: how do I get these files to talk, because there's clearly a lack of communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of [EAGLView initWith…](http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_e_a_g_l_view.html) methods have changed. In your case you simply need to add the remaining additional parameters as described in the link.

Comment: It's not that simple. Because I am porting the code over from an earlier iteration, I used a cocos2d template to get me started. This template has a Platforms folder, with MAC and iOS subfolders.

Comment: Before you ask, yes I selected the cocos2d iOS template, and it still saddled me with this Mac crap. http://i207.photobucket.com/albums/bb289/teh_Mac/App-h3.png ^There you can see how EAGLView has no definition http://i207.photobucket.com/albums/bb289/teh_Mac/app-h2.png ^There you can see EAGLView.h clearly exists, altho in an iOS subfolder of Platform
http://i207.photobucket.com/albums/bb289/teh_Mac/app-h1.png
^Here's the current cocos2d.h file
http://i207.photobucket.com/albums/bb289/teh_Mac/App-h4.png
^Here's the App.m Implementation of the EAGLView mthd. Note how EAGLView txt is colorless.